# Make div not affect other div's size

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a messenging website that look like Facebook Messenger as follow. The problem is that when user send a message that is shorter than 13 characters then the message box wrapped around will become longer than the message due to the sender's name above it.

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF16h.png)

Here is the code:

```
<img src="/images/phatdeptrai.jpg" style="width: 28px;border-radius: 50%;float: left;clear: both;margin-left: 7px;margin-right: 7px;position: relative;top: 38px;">
    <div style="float: left;max-width: 45%;">
    <div style="font-size: .6875rem;color: #65676b;margin-left: 13px;margin-top: 10px;">Hoàng Phát đẹp trai</div>
    <div style="background-color: #e4e6eb;border-radius: 20px;padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;margin-top: 2px;">
        <div style="color: black;">'.$row['body'].'</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the inner div into a span that is `display: inline-block;`. And move the styles of the outer div to the span. You can leave the margin.

```
<img src="/images/phatdeptrai.jpg" style="width: 28px;border-radius: 50%;float: left;clear: both;margin-left: 7px;margin-right: 7px;position: relative;top: 38px;">
<div style="float: left;max-width: 45%;">
<div style="font-size: .6875rem;color: #65676b;margin-left: 13px;margin-top: 10px;">Hoàng Phát đẹp trai</div>
<div style="margin-top: 2px;">
    <span style="display: inline-block; padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px; color: black; background-color: #e4e6eb;border-radius: 20px;"> sas</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Your answer will only solve the text shorter than 5 characters but not for long one. The long one will appear like this: [link](https://i.imgur.com/o8jDb2W.png)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check for longer text. I changed my answer, that might work.